# How to scroll inside a panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to scroll inside a panel based on a selected option.

Let's say:

- If the user selects **Section-1** then I want to scroll down to **Section-1** inside the panel
- If the user selects **Section-2** then I want to scroll down to **Section-2** and so on. I'm trying to use the **scrollTo** method but I'm stuck because the value 100 will need to change based on user's selection. Does anyone know how to make this work? Thanks a lot in advance!

> cmp.scrollTo('top', 100, true);

Here's [**LIVE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/4o85qugv/1/)

```
var filterPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
bodyPadding: 5,  // Don't want content to crunch against the borders
width: 300,
height: 400,
autoScroll: true,
title: 'Sections',
items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    height: 100,
    html: 'Section-1',
    style: {
   borderColor: 'black',
   borderStyle: 'solid',
    },
}......
.......
```

**NOTE:**
- If the user selects Section 3 then scroll down to Panel 3 and show it on the top. Please, see attached picture.

[image]

Comment: You can also consider using [fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for that. If you have a fullscreen structure, this is the best library for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scrollIntoView`:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        // The data store containing the list of states
        var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
            data: [{
                "abbr": "section1",
                "name": "Section-1"
            }, {
                "abbr": "section2",
                "name": "Section-2"
            }, {
                "abbr": "section3",
                "name": "Section-3"
            }, {
                "abbr": "section4",
                "name": "Section-4"
            }, {
                "abbr": "section5",
                "name": "Section-5"
            }, {
                "abbr": "section6",
                "name": "Section-6"
            }, {
                "abbr": "section7",
                "name": "Section-7"
            }]
        });

        // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose Section',
            store: states,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                change: function(field, v) {
                    var toScroll = filterPanel.getComponent(v);


                    var s = filterPanel.getScrollable();
                    s.scrollIntoView(toScroll.el);
                }
            }
        });

        var filterPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            bodyPadding: 5, // Don't want content to crunch against the borders
            width: 300,
            height: 400,
            autoScroll: true,
            title: 'Sections',
            items: Array(7).fill(null).map((_, i) => ({
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 100,
                itemId: 'section' + (i + 1),
                html: 'Section' + (i + 1),
                style: {
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    borderStyle: 'solid',
                },
            })),
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input bro!